# POST request payload in python not reaching PHP server

Tags: python, php, session, python-requests

I am trying to send a JSON payload with session request in python to a PHP server.
The session itself is established and cookies are accepted by the server but when I print out the `$_POST`, it returns an empty array.
It looks like the payload is not being sent with the request or maybe PHP doesn't recognize it.

Client Side - Python:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://prov.is.st.com/eventpost.php'
    payload = {
        'script': 'pyt.sh',
        'status': 'Success'
    }

    s = requests.Session()
    s.cookies.set('provisioning', cookie, domain='prov.is.st.com')
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    s.headers.update(headers)
    response = s.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)
    print(response.text)
```

Server Side - PHP:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
 $status = $_POST['status'];
}
else{
  $status=0;
}

if (isset($_POST['script'])) {
  $script=$_POST['script'];
} else {
  $script="unknown";
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['provisioning'])) {
  $cookie=$_COOKIE['provisioning'];
   print "OK: Message accepted: [$status][$script]\n";
  }
 else {
  print "ERROR: NO cookie provided.\n";
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
)
OK: Message accepted: [0][unknown]
```

Comment: Typo: `$POST['script']` should be `$_POST['script']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation here: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests, in order to post JSON data, you should use either of the following ways:

```
import json
...
response = s.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), verify = False)
```

or

```
...
response = s.post(url, json = payload, verify = False)
```

Note, the `json` parameter is ignored if either `data` or `files` is passed.

Using the `json` parameter in the request will change the `Content-Type` in the header to `application/json`.